# Narrowing conversion of ‘(((int)a) + -1)’ from ‘int’ to ‘int16_t {aka short int}’ inside { }

Tags: c++

I have the following 'test.cpp' file:

```
#include <cstdint>

struct Struct
{
    int16_t val;
};

int main()
{
        int16_t a = 0;
        //Struct b = {.val = a}; // No warning
        Struct b = {.val = a-1}; // Warning
        (void)b;
        return 0;
}
```

When compiling with 'g++ -std=c++11 -o test test.cpp', I get the following warning:

```
test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
test.cpp:12:29: warning: narrowing conversion of ‘(((int)a) + -1)’ from ‘int’ to ‘int16_t {aka short int}’ inside { } [-Wnarrowing]
         Struct b = {.val = a-1};
                             ^
```

Is there a way to get rid of it?

Comment: With pedantic flag, both lines trigger:  warning: ISO C++ does not allow C99 designated initializers [-Wpedantic]

Comment: @2785528 funny, I also added that in my answer ^^ (I always compile with `-pedantic -Wextra`)

Comment: @2785528 I think designated initializers are only available since C++11. Maybe this is the cause of the warning

Answer (score 4):

The type of `a` is promoted to `int` when subtracting 1.
You can get around that by performing a `static_cast` on the whole expression:

```
    Struct b = { .val = static_cast<int16_t>(a - 1) };
```

Note that arithmetic operations may be faster for certain platforms (i.e. x86) if they are done with the normal `int` type.

Comment: Thanks, though I feel like there will be two conversions : 'a' to 'int' and then 'a-1' to 'int16_t', whereas no conversion should be needed. (The use of int16_t is aimed at reducing space requirement)

Comment: @fflorian Your compiler will almost surely not actually do conversions there. They are needed so your code complies with the type system, but not for the actual arithmetic.

Answer (score 1):

```
    Struct b = {.val = (int16_t)(a-1)}; // cast as expected, by default formula produces int
```

---

Note that if I compile with -pedantic :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ g++ -pedantic c.cc
c.cc: In function ‘int main()’:
c.cc:12:20: warning: ISO C++ does not allow C99 designated initializers [-Wpedantic]
         Struct b = {.val = (int16_t)(a-1)}; // Warning
```

better to have

```
Struct b = {(int16_t)(a-1)}; // no warning even with -pedantic
```